# Does a global install of a local node project just create executable links back to the project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-scripts

[I'm doing some work on a command line interface](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli), and to test it from the root of the project I do:

```
npm i -g
```

After this I can test the command on various projects.

IIUC running `npm i -g` creates global links that are executable, but the actual files being run are the original project files?

Running:

```
    ole@mki:~/SuperflyCSS/cli$ npm list -g | grep superfly
    ├─┬ @superflycss/cli@4.1.2 -> /home/ole/SuperflyCSS/cli
    │ ├─┬ @superflycss/pli@3.0.0
```

Seems to indicate that this is the case.

I just want to triple check because I'm getting an odd scenario where it looks as if NPM is making a copy.

[This issue is related to this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54271046/logging-what-plugins-postcss-is-running-with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally installed modules are placed in "/usr/local/lib/node_modules" (or its equivalent on your system, which you can find by running "npm list -g").

As for the binaries that are globally installed, symbolic links to them are placed in "/usr/local/bin", but you can find out where they are on your system by using "npm bin -g".

For example, browserify installed to "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify", and has a "/bin/cmd.js" file that is linked as:"/usr/local/bin/browserify->/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/bin/cmd.js".

Comment: Cool!  This explains a lot.  Looks like it's `/usr/lib/node_modules` on Ubuntu.  Found it by running `find / -xdev 2>/dev/null -name "@superflycss"`