# Logging what plugins PostCSS is running with?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postcss, postcss-loader, postcss-cli

[I'm writing a CLI that uses PostCSS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superflycss/cli) and even though I don't have `uncss` in the plugins array, I'm getting error reports from `uncss`.  Is there  a way to have PostCSS print out what plugins are currently loaded?

[This issue is related to this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270592/does-a-global-install-of-a-local-node-project-just-create-executable-links-back)